# Conditional rolling sum loop in R

Tags: r

I'm looking for some kind kind of conditional rolling sum I thought a while loop would do what I need, but I'm having trouble implementing it. So this should look like PCAR[1]*time[1]+PCAR[2]*time[2]+PCAR[3]*time[3] etc where [] references the row of the column, and this would loop until the cumulative time value reachs <= 100 years, then the loop should add this value to a column and then start again until cumulative time is between 100 and <= 200, and so on until the bottom of the data set. It's going to be applied to datasets of varying sizes with tens of thousands of years in.

I hope that makes sense. In the example data below the PCAR_BIN column is what I'm aiming for as the outcome.

```
df <- tibble(cumulative.time = c(20,40,60,80,100, 120,140,160,180,200), 
             PCAR =1:10,
             time = 1:10,
             depth.along.core = 1:10, 
             Age.cal.BP = 1:10, 
             AFBD = 1:10, 
             assumed.C = rep(0.5, 10),
             PCAR_BIN = c(55,330,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

The function looks like

```
MBA <- function(data) {
  require(dplyr)
  data %>% mutate(PCAR=((lead(depth.along.core) - depth.along.core )/(lead(Age.cal.BP) - Age.cal.BP))*AFBD*assumed.C*10000,
                  PCA_NCP = PCAR*(lead(Age.cal.BP)-Age.cal.BP), 
                  PCA_NCP[is.na(PCA_NCP)] <- 0, 
                  CCP_Bottom_Up = rev(cumsum(rev(PCA_NCP))),
                  CCP_Top_Down = CCP_Bottom_Up[1]- CCP_Bottom_Up,
                  PCAR_BIN = ifelse(cumulative.time <= 100, sum(PCAR*time+lead(PCAR)*lead(time),NA)
                    )}
```

Obviously I had no luck with the ifelse satement, as it would only work for one iteration of time and the sum is wrong. I've tried similar with while and for loops but with no luck. Part of the problem is I'm not sure how to express the sum that I need. I've also tried binning the data with case_when, and working off that, but with no luck again.

Thanks people :)

EDIT

Following Martins method I now have the function working up to creating the ROLLSUM Column, I now need to create a column that will give the maximum value for each century group. Running the code from slicemax onward gives me the error:
Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object '*tmp*' not found

I've added the real data too.

```
dput(head(EMC))
structure(list(depth.along.core = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 
5.5), Age.cal.BP = c(-56.016347625, -55.075825875, -54.201453125, 
-53.365755375, -52.541258625, -51.700488875), time = c(0.94052175, 
0.87437275, 0.83569775, 0.82449675, 0.84076975, 0.88451675), 
    cumulative.time = c(0.94052175, 1.8148945, 2.65059225, 3.475089, 
    4.31585875, 5.2003755), AFBD = c(0.0711, 0.057, 0.0568, 0.0512, 
    0.0559, 0.0353), assumed.C = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

MBA <- function(data) {
  require(dplyr)
  data %>% mutate(PCAR=((lead(depth.along.core) - depth.along.core )/(lead(Age.cal.BP) - Age.cal.BP))*AFBD*assumed.C*10000,
                  PCA_NCP = PCAR*(lead(Age.cal.BP)-Age.cal.BP), 
                  PCA_NCP[is.na(PCA_NCP)] <- 0, 
                  CCP_Bottom_Up = rev(cumsum(rev(PCA_NCP))),
                  CCP_Top_Down = CCP_Bottom_Up[1]- CCP_Bottom_Up)%>%
                  slice(1:(n()-1))%>%
                  group_by(Century = cut(cumulative.time, breaks = seq(0, max(cumulative.time), 100)))%>%
                  mutate(ROLLSUM = rev(cumsum(PCAR*time)))%>%
                  slice_max(order_by = ROLLSUM, n = 1) %>%
                  pull(ROLLSUM)%>%
                  df$ROLLSUM <- c(groupMaxima, rep(NA, nrow(df) - length(groupMaxima)))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
# Get cumulative sums by group (assuming per century groups)
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Century = cut(cumulative.time, 
                         breaks = seq(0, max(cumulative.time), 100))) %>%
  mutate(ROLLSUM = rev(cumsum(PCAR * time)))

# Get maximum of each group
groupMaxima <- df %>%
  slice_max(order_by = ROLLSUM, n = 1) %>%
  pull(ROLLSUM)

# Fill column as desired
df$ROLLSUM <- c(groupMaxima, rep(NA, nrow(df) - length(groupMaxima)))
```

We simply create a factor column to group the cumulative time column by centuries and use that factor to sum up the values. Lastly we edit the rolling sum column to contain only the max values and fill the other rows with `NA`.

```
# A tibble: 10 x 10
# Groups:   Group [2]
   cumulative.time  PCAR  time depth.along.core Age.cal.BP  AFBD assumed.C PCAR_BIN Group     ROLLSUM
             <dbl> <int> <int>            <int>      <int> <int>     <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>       <int>
 1              20     1     1                1          1     1       0.5       55 (0,100]        55
 2              40     2     2                2          2     2       0.5      330 (0,100]       330
 3              60     3     3                3          3     3       0.5       NA (0,100]        NA
 4              80     4     4                4          4     4       0.5       NA (0,100]        NA
 5             100     5     5                5          5     5       0.5       NA (0,100]        NA
 6             120     6     6                6          6     6       0.5       NA (100,200]      NA
 7             140     7     7                7          7     7       0.5       NA (100,200]      NA
 8             160     8     8                8          8     8       0.5       NA (100,200]      NA
 9             180     9     9                9          9     9       0.5       NA (100,200]      NA
10             200    10    10               10         10    10       0.5       NA (100,200]      NA
```

Edit:

For this special case:

```
MBA <- function(data) {
  require(dplyr)
  data <- data %>% mutate(PCAR = ((lead(depth.along.core) - depth.along.core )/(lead(Age.cal.BP) - Age.cal.BP))*AFBD*assumed.C*10000,
                  PCA_NCP = PCAR*(lead(Age.cal.BP)-Age.cal.BP), 
                  PCA_NCP[is.na(PCA_NCP)] <- 0, 
                  CCP_Bottom_Up = rev(cumsum(rev(PCA_NCP))),
                  CCP_Top_Down = CCP_Bottom_Up[1]- CCP_Bottom_Up) 
  
  data <- data %>%
    group_by(CTIME = cut(cumsum(cumulative.time), 
                         breaks = seq(0, max(cumsum(cumulative.time), na.rm = T), 100))) %>%
    mutate(ROLLSUM = rev(cumsum(PCAR*time))) 
  
  groupMaxima <- data %>% slice_max(order_by = ROLLSUM, n = 1) %>%
    pull(ROLLSUM)
  
  data$ROLLSUM <- c(groupMaxima, rep(NA, nrow(data) - length(groupMaxima)))
  data
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for both your answers, I should of said in my question that my actual cumulative time is not in set intervals, it comes from Bayesian modelling of radiocarbon dates, and so is fairly random and to 6 decimal places, I may of over simplified it in my example data. I've tried adding martins answer into my function but it returns the error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Century`.
x 'to' must be a finite number. I think this is probably due to my cumulative time data not falling on 100

Comment: Well, try using `dput(head(yourData))` to give us a snapshot of your real data.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks a lot for your help, its getting there. I had no idea I could use dput like that, very useful! Please see the edit.

Comment: So you want to sum up the values until the cumulative time this 100, then start at zero until the next total duration of 100 is reached?

Comment: Hi Martin, Yeah, so it would be just as you showed me the first time with the max for 0-100 then 100-200 etc. It worked perfectly with the example data. The first error was due to the final value in my real data being NA so I used slice to remove that row as it is only needed for the first few calculations. Now I'm just stuck trying to incorporate the last bit of your code into my function.

Comment: I added a modified `MBA` function. Please check if it does what you desire.

Comment: Hi Martin, you got me there thanks a lot. I ended up just grouping  sorting by descending and slicing the data as I realised I didn't need anything but the group data following the last mutate, thanks a lot for all your help thougj,

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways, if your steps are really steps of 100 years, and the values go 0,20,40 in constant intervals- you can do this natively:

```
steps = 100
intervals = 20
ratio = steps / intervals
columns = df[,c("PCAR","time")] 
indices = rep(ratio,nrow(df)) %>% cumsum
    
PCAR_BIN = lapply(indices,function(x){
             localRange = (x-ratio):x
             sum(columns[localRange,1] * columns[localRange,2])
           })%>% unlist
```

we can now bind `PICAR_BIN`:

```
df = cbind(df,PICAR_BIN)
```